# Select top 1 from inner join subquery

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I wish to select the first value of a column in the inner join for each successful join.

```
@getEndDate = SELECT c.CustomerId, c.ProductId FROM @customer AS c
INNER JOIN (SELECT (DateTime?) EndDate AS EndDate, (int) CustomerId AS CustomerId 
FROM @Installation 
ORDER BY EndDate FETCH 1 ROW OFFSET 0 ROWS) AS i ON c.CustomerId == i.CustomerId
```

By doing this I get the EndDate lowest EndDate in @Installation where the join ciretia is met.

How can I get only the first value from the inner join subquery for each successful join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the FIRST_VALUE function on INNER JOIN SELECT:

Check this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/analytic/first-value

Comment: That's great! No idea why I didn't find that documentation.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chose to do the following in the inner join subquery:

```
(SELECT (DateTime?) MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate, (int) CustomerID AS CustomerID FROM 
@Installation GROUP BY CustomerID)
```

Works for my case.